# SpriteKit + xcode6 present scene crash app

Tags: objective-c, ios8, sprite-kit

I am creating a simple MainMenu scene and on "play" button select I move to the Game scene as follows:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {    
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
        SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

        if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"play"]) {

                SKScene *gameScene  = [[GameScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
                SKTransition *fadeTransition = [SKTransition fadeWithColor:[UIColor blackColor] duration:0.3];
                [self.view presentScene:gameScene transition:fadeTransition];


        }

    }
}
```

After the transition app crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1). I am currently running Xcode6 + SpritKit/Objective-C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem - apparently caused by particle targetNode assignment:

```
starParticle.targetNode = self.scene;
```

which probably should have been released before presenting other scene